# Trouble getting shapely to run

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, shapely, geos

I downloaded the GDAL complete Framework von Kyngchaos which also includes the GEOS Framework and shapely for python.

I can `import shapely` without a problem, but when I try to perform some "geo related" operations (like `shape()`) I get this error message:

> Failed `CDLL(/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)`

This is my `echo $PATH` output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:
/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/:
/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib/:
/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/:
/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin
```

I checked, the GEOS framework is in there. Any ideas why shapely is not wirking?

Comment: For what it is worth, and if you have the option, it is quite painless to use the Anaconda python distribution version of shapely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to point your system to where the GEOS Framework is located.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761682/python-cant-import-shapely):

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If it works, add it to your $PATH!

Answer (score 1):

The Shapely distributions I am making for OS X (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely#downloads) have GEOS included and you won't have to think about library paths at all. If you're using Python 2.7, 3.4, or 3.5 and OS X 10.6+, `pip install shapely` is the best way to get it.